# <mx:ButtonBar/> set width for individual buttons

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3, padding, buttonbar

I have a buttonbar which has both buttons with only small icons and buttons with short text labels. Problem is that each button gets huge padding while I want to set width of the button relative to its contents. Below is illustration of my problem:
Current one https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0hdb.png
With buttonWidth=32 https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlbEq.png

I can set buttonWidth to 32 for my buttonbar which works fine for my icons, but not for text. Is there way to remove that huge padding of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are after there, you can use a layout inside the buttonbar tag something like this:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout variableColumnWidth="true" gap="0"/>
</s:layout>
```

Comment: Looks like <mx:Buttonbar> doesn't have layout and things break in my app if I change it to <s:Buttonbar> :/ My buttonbar is defined as <mx:ButtonBar id="buttonBar" dataProvider="{toolbar}" itemClick="buttonBar_itemClickHandler(event)" height="28" x="0" y="21" />